# Why can't I use my Charizardite Y card/plate in Pokemon Duel?

Tags: pokemon-duel

My Charizardite Y card/plate is not working even if satisfies all the set conditions.

As you can see in the following picture, I have no Mega Evolved Pokemon and I also have a Charizard.

[image: my deck]

But as you can see in the following picture below, I am not able to use the Charizardite Y plate.
[image: failed to use charizardite y card]

Why can't I use the plate?

**Edit**: I have also placed my Charizard in the field but even then I can't use my charizardite y card as you can see in the following picture 
[image]

Comment: Can you list your deck?

Comment: My deck has empolium, Charizard,  zapdos, moltres, lucario and heatran

Comment: Possible bug? Contact their support and find out what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a Charizard Y figure? To mega evolve, you need a Charizard figure, the Charizard Y plate, **and** a Charizard Y figure.

Comment: Yeah I came to know about this in recent times

Answer (score 1):

The Charizardite Y card/plate text says "Choose one of your Charizard on the field..." Your Charizard is on the bench, not on the field. Move your Charizard onto the field and then use the plate.

Comment: Tried that too but of no use.